# How to loop over a vector of integers in Rust?

Tags: arrays, loops, vector, rust, iterator

I know the code below works:

```rust
// method 1
fn vec_loop(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
  v.iter().map(|x| x * 2).collect()
}
```

However, I was wondering if it were possible to do it as such:

```rust
// method 2
fn vec_loop(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
  for i in v.iter_mut() {
    // TODO: Fill this up so that each element in the Vec `v` is multiplied by two.
  }
  v
}
```

So far I've been unable to run the iteration using `iter_mut()`.I'd appreciate it if:

1. Someone could shed light on how to run the code in this manner.
2. Shed insight into whether or not there are any performance variations between method 1 and method 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write to `i`, like to a C pointer:

```
fn vec_loop(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
  for i in v.iter_mut() {
    *i *= 2;
  }
  v
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    
    println!("{:?}", vec_loop(vec));
}
```

As for performance, you can always measure it! Also, `collect` should allocate a new vector, while the approach with the loop modifies existing memory in-place, so it should be faster on big vectors. To me, `v.iter().map(|x| x * 2).collect()` looks cleaner, and I'd use that for readability purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [dereference operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator) (`*`):

```rust
fn vec_loop(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in v.iter_mut() {
      *i *= 2;
    }
    v
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand onto the previous answer by pretzelhammer, you can mutate the original vector as well without returning any data.

```
fn vec_loop_1(v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.iter().map(|x| x * 2).collect()
}

fn vec_loop_2(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in v.iter_mut() {
        *i *= 2;
    }
    v
}

fn vec_loop_3(v: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for i in v.iter_mut() {
        *i *= 2;
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(vec_loop_1(vec![1, 2, 3]), vec![2, 4, 6]);
    assert_eq!(vec_loop_2(vec![1, 2, 3]), vec![2, 4, 6]);
    assert_eq!(vec_loop_1(vec![1, 2, 3]), vec_loop_2(vec![1, 2, 3]));
    let mut new_vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    vec_loop_3(&mut new_vec);
    assert_eq!(new_vec, vec![2, 4, 6]);
}
```

vec_loop_3 will mutate its borrowed data instead of taking in a vector and returning a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can dereference and mutate mutable references using the deref `*` operator:

```rust
fn vec_loop_1(v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.into_iter().map(|x| x * 2).collect()
}

fn vec_loop_2(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in v.iter_mut() {
        *i *= 2;
    }
    v
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(vec_loop_1(vec![1, 2, 3]), vec![2, 4, 6]);
    assert_eq!(vec_loop_2(vec![1, 2, 3]), vec![2, 4, 6]);
    assert_eq!(vec_loop_1(vec![1, 2, 3]), vec_loop_2(vec![1, 2, 3]));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=99dab0386cf0f83a389e24835f9c48cf)

---

> Shed insight into whether or not there are any performance variations between method 1 and method 2.

`vec_loop_1` allocates a new `Vec` and `vec_loop_2` does not. The latter will be faster and use less memory.