# Why is Rust's default sort function slightly slower than my Selection Sort for small arrays?

Tags: performance, sorting, rust, benchmarking, selection-sort

I'm quite new to Rust, so I might be missing something simple. I am using Rust 1.70.0-nightly. Here is the necessary code:

```rust
fn selection_sort(original_vec: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in 0..original_vec.len()-1 {
        let mut smallest: usize = i;
        for j in i+1..original_vec.len() {
            if original_vec[j] < original_vec[smallest] {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        if smallest != i {
            original_vec.swap(i, smallest);
        }
    };
    original_vec.to_vec()
}

// helper function for testing (uses builtin sort function)
fn rust_sort<A, T>(mut array: A) -> A
where
    A: AsMut<[T]>,
    T: Ord,
{
    let slice = array.as_mut();
    slice.sort();

    array
}

const TEST_VECS: [[i32; 10]; 6] = [
    [1, 3, 2, 9, 6, 7, 4, 10, 8, 5],
    [1, 2, 7, 2, 9, 9, 7, 10, 2, 1],
    [0, 4, 1, 3, 9, 12, 3, 0, 13, 8],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [-1, -5, -10, 1, 10, 2, -123, -34, 0, -32],
    [i32::MAX, -32984, i32::MIN, 31648, 5349857, -30954, -2343285, 0, 1, i32::MIN],
];

#[bench]
fn bench_rust_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in TEST_VECS {
            (&mut i.to_vec()).sort()
        }
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_selection_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in TEST_VECS {
            selection_sort(&mut i.to_vec());
        }
    })
}
```

When I run `cargo bench`:

```bash
$ cargo bench
  Compiling rust-algs v0.1.0 (/home/josia/projects/rust-algs)
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.25s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/release/deps/rustalgs-ae260c07593c3aad)

running 3 tests
test test_selection_sort ... ignored
test bench_rust_sort      ... bench:         106 ns/iter (+/- 8)
test bench_selection_sort ... bench:         102 ns/iter (+/- 9)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 1 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 7.65s
```

I tried this many times, and even renamed the testing function to change the order of testing. No matter what, my custom selection sort function still performs faster. I'm guessing the problem lies within the fact that I had to call a function to wrap the main default sort function. Calling the actual function wouldn't work, because even if I clone the `TEST_VECS` constant in the benching function as a vector, the sorting function would just keep sorting it, which won't let the other benching iterations to sort it. If I cloned the constant within the benching closure, it would affect the bench iteration's performance greatly and I wouldn't be able to just benchmark the code I'm trying to run.

Is there a problem with the way I am benchmarking these functions, or is my custom function somehow just faster?

Comment: Making an algorithm non-terrible for large cases often makes it slightly slower for tiny cases.  Here you have a sort that's optimized purely for tiny cases, using an O(N^2) algorithm that's fast-ish for 10 elements.  The standard library sort probably checks the size before eventually doing an Insertion Sort or something as a base-case for small problems. It also has extra call/return overhead unless Rust's sort fully inlines, but that should be under a nanosecond.  So this looks plausible even if nothing got optimized away.  100 ns is probably reasonable for six 10-element sorts.

Comment: I don't know Rust well at all, but how does `selection_sort(&mut i.to_vec());` prevent the result from being optimized away?  Are you compiling with less than full optimization, or are you just getting lucky that the compiler fails to optimize away the useless work?

Comment: Try creating a vector with 1000, 10 000, 100 000 elements and see if this still holds. Spoiler - it won't.

Comment: Also create vectors from arrays **outside** of `b.iter`'s closure, because now you are measuring heap allocation and copying memory in addition to just sorting.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze: You do need to at least copy inside the iter, unless you *want* to keep sorting the same sorted array.  (Selection Sort doesn't take advantage of that; Insertion Sort does, so that might make `.sort()` much faster if that's what it uses for a base-case.)  And making tons of copies ahead of time and looping over them will give you cache misses, which is worse than a couple AVX vectors of load/store that hit in L1d cache.  (10x 32-bit elements is 40 bytes, one YMM vector and one scalar 64-bit copy if compiling for modern x86, like `-C target-cpu=x86-64-v3` or `native`)

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I tried creating vectors outside of the closure, but now the default sort is around `33ns` and the custom sort is around `201ns`. I get that the default sort should be faster than most algorithms, but I'm still not believing that it would have this much of difference, especially with what @PeterCordes said about the test vectors being small and Rust's sort being optimized for larger cases. I think the problem is with the cloning required for each iteration of the benchmarking. If don't clone, it would just solve it once and solve already solved vectors

Comment: @PeterCordes how would I prevent the code being optimized away, if it is? I have tried researching and learned about `black_box`. It apparently fixes the code being optimized when benchmarking, but since I am new to Rust, I couldn't really understand much about it. How would I use something like that in this scenario?

Comment: Probably `black_box(sorted_vec[2]);` or something to force it to load an element of the result, or maybe just to have it in memory without forcing it to load into a register.  It's possible it could optimize away work that it can prove doesn't lead to arr[2] if it's super clever, but probably fine.  Perhaps `black_box(sorted_vec)` to tell it the whole array is an input to the black box.  (So assign the sorted array to a variable so you can reference it, or I guess use the `.sort()` return value.)  I briefly skimmed https://gendignoux.com/blog/2022/01/31/rust-benchmarks.html

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort confirms that for short slices, an in-place Insertion Sort is used.  If this does inline, it might be fully unrolling that sort the way it is for Selection Sort.  Or not, since Selection does less data movement but more compares, so is maybe easier for the compiler to keep more values in registers as it compares.  (Insertion Sort has an O(N) best case for already-sorted data, unlike Selection Sort.  When you aren't hitting anywhere near that best case, maybe not surprising fully-unrolled Selection with `-C opt-level=3` is faster.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL:DR:**

- Rustc `-C opt-level=3` fully inlines and ***fully* unrolls** your `selection_sort` for this compile-time constant size=10.  With `opt-level=2` it inlines but compiles to a loop like the source.
- Rust's `.sort` uses Insertion Sort for sizes this small, but for some reason it *doesn't* inline.  So that's actually running a not-unrolled loop with a size that's a runtime-variable (as far as it knows).  Note the caller doing `mov  esi, 10` / ... / `call  core::slice::sort::insertion_sort_shift_left`.  I think this is the key thing that's making `.sort` slightly slower.
- Copying from `TEST_VECS` is fine although maybe a bit small; modern CPUs might be learning the pattern of branching with the branch predictors and doing better than you'd expect as part of a larger program for unsorted inputs of that size.  You could have more than 6 slices and still not be getting and L1d cache misses.

  It would be better to avoid alloc/dealloc inside the repeat loop.  (Use `.clone_from_slice` ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604714/how-can-i-copy-a-vector-to-another-location-and-reuse-the-existing-allocated-mem)) into a slice or vector that gets allocated outside the repeat loop).  Both loops are paying for the same alloc/dealloc overhead, and that should balance out.  The compiler already does the actual copying efficiently here.

  Rust's `.sort` doesn't internally alloc anything for slice sizes this small (using Insertion Sort), and passing/returning a Vec optimizes away to just in-place sorting, no extra copying.
- [`black_box` could make this more robust](https://gendignoux.com/blog/2022/01/31/rust-benchmarks.html) against potential optimizations that defeat the repeat-loop, but it looks like that isn't happening with current versions.
- Selection Sort has O(N^2) time complexity (best and worst case). Insertion Sort is O(N) for already sorted arrays, which is one reason it's the standard choice for small problems (and sub-problems of divide-and-conquer algorithms for larger arrays), but in general is O(N^2) average and worst case.  For large problems, all O(N^2) sorts are garbage, so `.sort` and `.sort_unstable` use O(N log N) algorithms that are much faster than `selection_sort`. Murasame's answer measured a factor of 15 speed difference for size=1000.  (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort / https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable)
- If your CPU is Skylake-family, you should look for a Rust equivalent of [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256646/how-can-i-mitigate-the-impact-of-the-intel-jcc-erratum-on-gcc) - without controlling for that factor, one microbenchmark might get bitten by it while another doesn't.

So we can say that Selection Sort compiles to faster asm with current Rustc with `-C opt-level=3`, for small compile-time-constant Vecs that aren't (close to) already sorted.  Based on what we're seeing in the asm as the apparent reason for these results, I expect it would be different if any of those factors were different.  Perhaps even different tuning defaults for different ISAs could make it not fully unroll.  Also, it's somewhat important that mainstream x86-64 CPUs can handle such large loops fully efficiently (via a large-enough uop cache).

---

#### `selection_sort` inlined and fully unrolled, `.sort` didn't

Your measurements are probably correct for this specific case, of **size=10 as compile-time constant** that the compiler can see.  `rustc -C opt-level=3` is **fully inlining and *fully* unrolling your `selection_sort`**, but emitting a `call` to the standard library's Insertion Sort.  So `.sort()` includes the loop overhead of dealing with a runtime-variable slice size.

(I don't know how to get the Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer to show me asm for the actual `#[bench]` functions, so I made my own simple counted-loop caller on the assumption that inlining choices would be basically the same into `b.iter(|| { ... })` loops.  [Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DEArgoKkl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywZ7HAGTwNMAHLuAEaYxCAA7ABMpAAOqAqEdgwubh568Ym2Ar7%2BQSyh4dGWmNbZDEIETMQEqe6eXCVlyZXVBLmBIWGRMeZtdemNfTUd%2BYU9AJSWqCbEyOwcAKRRAMxgYIsArABCVJhMBLOYEASY5hNbACKLGgCCAPT3y2sbO3sHRxChDMgIAPrBAzIADWANQqgum2udxutyoDAA1FZMDZkn8FCQCBASHhgH4xH8AG4okAI5YANhYJgICIAaijFisnHgVlFGdgJgiALTsukMpkstkrbBkiLbWEIyUI/jEBF4OWIjQAOiVOLxzFoRJRSvoDAgEy5XFF4ruUrNCPoNKpNIULDE9HMpLMeAAXpgyStLnLGSbbuapTKEdoFd6otsuCq1fjNcTkDrGPrjRL/ea8FQEVGNVrkFtttorh6nBniLjo9nc7b7WcCAXFmLkymU5XaA6aYyvfmVr7G2a69C/Sm%2Bw3U%2Bnm62Eet23Kk6ae5LMwTY0qFAB3JixCB4UhIu0t6sXLvD3sRfvH66H2fzkvqxfaojZ/Wwocwu6PBEIUqxMLSkw/crSkgEVOcw/GABEIDMM4EWCEw6FsREMRqH8/2SC47nhBFTHMdFMUZJxbm3AAVdkIGtBFqmIJgAE9SVuTkeWFBFblhFcP2ITBh1uWiFAAWWpPDc2IqF2VIYdCNJAB5Yh0FEmF60vC1MBtWg8HmD0vQo6ilSYBQ/mtR8LwHSUFBU%2BZl0xAzfWHTSqKfE8nzuNAGHMBFCOwIRCL%2BWlsCcIRSVzXNBR9BEuA0K5gvJWtPTJHZh1zRoERWbcYgRABObdyW3CJt2kEKNG3AAObdNiuWSjJi8Nkqyqq0u3dKEWyvKaq4Uq4p2fKEVyhKktqkKUp6jquB6grWoU%2BKap63LNgy6qESK3rQtG8rc0NbcuWm7lQu3BKtoRFLDVWNaVlyjquVZJbex2QUQBAHjbgADSOqJUoK3LrtugBJAJtxWLhyUkebNmOl7Nkas6NFSzZcq5VZJFZAqNsG7d3p4r6lvCwyn1WXNvl%2BcK7liExglhDDcf%2BLCCBwmovn8qJKWpBFtkYX4wk5OtuylYIlUIMIIDrJx%2BZncqzUDeU/Fc9zPO83yhbnSU%2Bbpsi8CVe9Y31CZzOptDhalZ9lpPbW9axlYceZhB8duQnifQxEyfRUoUXKKmsWCWn6ZpJmfjYtn5PKrmeeIPmIgF4PZZTUWQzcjyvJ8oQw7nZFUQEZ2FfduUVdQB8JgPDn/T1s9Dfsl8HnuBEPoRdABDADgaWBBhUBXd8G6A1AEWAJS5RpIgkQQZudJYADZQID8yWxnYyYLYliESARYStknEVUO3E6dxCsSYUlBUL3PB4RAEQ2VbTjUlN9tDMGkmARNBf1OdBMMwL8DgtVBUFiI8ETfWgX%2BBBQLTwYF3QrzRGvCueA74ACp64EHARmWItgWBunImuKiZV/RvkMHfYeYRMDV1/mfFyGI2AIhYKgQkJhYi/zQLEKioEMzpkkBoaCVFgLQUwDKd0%2BxfhIkxEqd%2Bb4YI0kIHKSh9paH2lQMgD%2BFd9gtgke/SUEdxZRylrHeOPY3wUxThSJWGcs453keaIByc16px0arFE6sfQGPzrrIuzETwcCmLQTgmxeCeA4FoUgqBOAACVz7cNmGpZ4PBSAEE0I4qYwIQCsiVADFYBUNBcGepsAqqVyQrBWNNZxHBJBuPCV4zgvAFAgHymEjxjjSBwFgEgNALBYh0DCOQSgtT6n0HCAwXECACC0BQTQWgpxp6UFduU0gwR8TEBotwXgYzmATIksEbQjtOAhNqWwQQEkGA9PyVgGCwAnD2mKVM0gWA7RGHECM/A7FUTEkOZ4zAqgUTUgWCEvwpxsmeJUsESiEyXBYHyQQEsLBlkVKoAYYAChaR4EwCuCSX53EhP4IIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1AjN0DEAwRgQAU30HgYIxTYDMDYCAAwLoqLoiqLYZApAp7LIYRErxcDkiHK5EWV%2BBAuT0GJLQdsKxeCkLCCWLAZKoAUvYJgfA5QmViBMAsKIGgog8Gzk0R2yQHAMGcK4eoXg9WjC6OERomQkgCAGA0OICRLUMBNQUboQwHZJwqFUGo1q9BGPdW0R14whgetqAawYlgg3%2BudVMDEgTUVOJcXkkZ3iOCYXPpIjpwAuk9PArgQggFgkTF4GUrQmqPxMCwOEfUpAonHSVFwAqUQCrkiBhEDQEQW2ZP0JwXJpB3GeKTUUkpoTwlTCqYgEAMwCCEwsBQCALSGnEACKwBYFNJERgiCsJUdz5U4nQHoRFwhRDiDRfuzFah8m4tICuSisRgVxo4K4nt%2BSk0SWpFOuhKbzBps6d0qi4EXB1PnaPVkBah3lM1dWjdGSoPQZg52nJCa%2B2FMsIOotbLslRAQ6KpDqHNVTxnp4SQQA) - change which call is uncommented to see asm for the other one.)

Normally Insertion Sort is just as good as Selection Sort for unsorted data like yours (both N^2 with similar constant factor), but it does have more data movement which maybe doesn't lend itself as well to fully unrolling for a compile-time-constant `.len()`.  Or some difference in the way it comes from the standard library vs. your `selection_sort` being simple and fully there in the source file, and written for `i32` specifically?  But `.sort` does inline and optimize away the logic to choose `insertion_sort_shift_left` without any of the large-slice code still being present, so nothing is inherently stopping the compiler, it just chose not to.

Anyway, I think fully unrolling the outer and inner loops is what's making `selection_sort` fast here.  After copying a TEST_VEC into a newly-allocated Vec, the asm goes right into comparing, like

```
# rustc nightly -C opt-level=3  for x86-64
# inside the main repeat loop in  bench_selection_sort
...
        mov     edi, 40
        mov     esi, 4
        call    rbp              # call alloc
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB0_4          # check for null
# pointer to a slice of TEST_VECS in R15
# pointer to the newly-allocated Vec<i32> in RAX
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [r15]
        movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [r15 + 16]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rax], xmm0          # with -C target-cpu=x86-64-v3
        movups  xmmword ptr [rax + 16], xmm1     # just one YMM 32-byte copy is needed, vs. 2x 16-byte with baselien SSE2
        mov     rdx, qword ptr [r15 + 32]
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 32], rdx      # copy last 8 of the 40 bytes
# and now the sorting
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rax]
        mov     edi, dword ptr [rax + 8]
        xor     esi, esi
        cmp     dword ptr [rax + 4], ecx
        setl    sil                  # 0 or 1 according to vec[1] < vec[0]
        mov     r9d, 2
        cmp     edi, dword ptr [rax + 4*rsi]   # compare at a data-dependent address; surprising for Selection Sort
        jl      .LBB0_9
        mov     r9, rsi            # strange that this isn't a CMOV; the only branch to .LBB0_9 is the preceding line
.LBB0_9:
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rax + 28]   # load several elements
        mov     edi, dword ptr [rax + 24]   # that it's going to cmp/branch on later
        mov     r10d, dword ptr [rax + 16]
        mov     r8d, dword ptr [rax + 20]
        mov     ebx, dword ptr [rax + 12]
        mov     r11d, 3
        cmp     ebx, dword ptr [rax + 4*r9]
        jge     .LBB0_10
  ... over 400 more instructions before the bottom of the loop, mostly mov / cmp/jcc
```

---

#### Test data

Sorting the same data repeatedly is more or less fine, although "only" 6x 10-element sorts might be small enough for your CPU to learn the pattern of branching.  ([Modern IT-TAGE predictors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399395/how-does-branch-prediction-affect-performance-in-r) use previous history to index a prediction make it possible to predict patterns for the same branch, so this doesn't necessarily give the fully-unrolled selection_sort a big advantage, especially since you're sorting 6 different slices so even full unrolling doesn't make a branch go the same way every time.)  Your testing with `perf stat` finding only about 1.5% mispredict rate seems lowish, but that is including loop branches.  Try making the arrays a bit longer and/or adding another few.

A few years ago, I was playing with a hand-written asm Bubble Sort from a code-golf exercise, and my Skylake was able to learn its pattern of branching for input sizes up to about 14 elements IIRC, near-zero mispredicts until I made the size larger.  And that's Bubble Sort, one of the worst O(N^2) sorts, plus its loop branching.  I was benchmarking it with a caller that just did a couple `vmovdqa ymm` stores from vector regs, which is the cheapest possible way to re-generate a small input for an in-place sort.  Rust is loading that data each repeat-loop iteration since there are 6 different sources, but that's only negligibly more expensive.  Scalar loads inside the sort function can load right away without even waiting for the vector stores to commit to L1d cache; modern x86 CPUs have good [store-to-load forwarding](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/) for scalar reloads of vector stores.  Everything hits in L1d cache.

Another option would be a vectorized xorshift+ like in [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323845/whats-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-1-gb-text-file-containing-random-digits/324520#324520) to get fresh data to sort every iteration.  Using the sorted array as the seed for an [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) (like Murasame's answer) would be a way to benchmark latency instead of throughput, but will also have a store-forwarding stall when you do a SIMD vector load of the array that was just written by scalar stores.  (Assuming the compiler auto-vectorizes your loop.)

---

#### O(N^2) sorts like Selection Sort are slow on bigger arrays

I assume you already know this, but **Selection Sort has O(N^2) time complexity so it's garbage for larger sizes**.  Rust's [`.sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort) and [`.sort_unstable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable) use O(N log N) sorts for larger problems (iterative merge "inspired by timsort", or pattern-defeating quicksort respectively), but use Insertion Sort for small sizes, or sub-problems of the larger sorts. Here the size is a compile-time constant and Rust's `.sort` function can inline enough to optimize away branching on the size to pick a strategy, so it's just your selection_sort vs. the standard library's Insertion Sort (`core::slice::sort::insertion_sort_shift_left`) for problems of this size.

(Surprisingly, `.sort_unstable` inlines less ([Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/aPMfxs81W)), calling `core::slice::sort::recurse` which checks the size at run-time for being less than `21`, otherwise continuing into its quicksort.)

Insertion Sort and Selection Sort do well for small arrays where more complex  algorithms would spend too much time sub-dividing an already-small problem.  That's why real-world sorts use Insertion Sort once they've sub-divided and partially-sorted enough to create small sub-problems.  (Or a sorting network, perhaps using SIMD vectors.)

Stable sorting is irrelevant when the objects being sorted are simple integers, not a struct with a key and some other data.  Equal `i32` objects are indistinguishable.  But it seems `.sort` doesn't try to detect that since we get different asm from `.sort` and `.sort_unstable`.

---

#### `black_box`

You don't do anything to stop the sort from being optimized away; the resulting vector is unused.  But it appears current versions of `rustc -C opt-level=3` miss that optimization **so your benchmark appears valid.**

Using `black_box(sort_result)` would be [safer / future-proof](https://gendignoux.com/blog/2022/01/31/rust-benchmarks.html), although if the compiler did fully see through your benchmark it could just copy from already-sorted arrays to satisfy the `black_box` requirement to materialize a sort result somewhere.  So to be fully safe, you'd use `black_box` on the *input* slice or vector and then on the output; hopefully `black_box` makes the compiler forget what values are there, i.e. treat it like a function call that might have modified the slice, not just read it.

#### And avoiding alloc/dealloc

The copying is super cheap, just 2 vector (`movups`) and 1 scalar (`mov rdx, [r15 + 32]` / `mov [rax+32], rdx`) load+store.

But the alloc/dealloc could be avoided with a better benchmark.  I was wrong about this in comments; I was looking for a `call some_longer_name` but actually Rustc likes to load library function pointers into registers (if they're going to be called inside loops) so you have to watch for the `call` mnemonic to spot instructions like `call rbp`.

[How can I copy a vector to another location and reuse the existing allocated memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604714/how-can-i-copy-a-vector-to-another-location-and-reuse-the-existing-allocated-mem) describes how to use `.clone_from` or `.clone_from_slice()` to copy the data from a slice into an already-allocated `Vec`.  I looked at the asm to confirm that there were no `call` instructions inside the `for i in TEST_VECS {` loop, unlike the original.

```
use core::hint::black_box;

// I don't know how to get it to show asm for the #[bench] version
pub
fn xbench_selection_sort(a: i32) {
    // allocate correct amount of storage once, and redundantly copy into it because I don't know Rust very well
    let mut test_vec = TEST_VECS[0].to_vec();
    for _b in 0..a {  // just a counted repeat loop
        for i in TEST_VECS {
            //let mut test_vec = i.to_vec();  // would alloc/free inside the loop
            test_vec.clone_from_slice(&i);    // copy into already-allocated space
            black_box(&mut test_vec.as_slice());  // force the data (but not the pointers and size) to exist in memory
            selection_sort(&mut test_vec);
            black_box(&mut test_vec.as_slice());  // force the result data to exist.  Apparently costs at least 1 extra asm instruction somewhere, unfortunately.
     // actually this does store the pointers+length to the stack, not avoiding it like I hoped.

            //black_box(&mut test_vec[4]);   // or just ask for one element; often enough to stop a compiler from optimizing away a whole loop.
        }
    }
}
```

(**[Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DEArgoKkl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywYgAHNMcAZPAZMADl3ACNMYhAAdgBmUgAHVAVCOwYXNw9vaSSU2wEAoNCWCKi4y0xrfIYhAiZiAgz3Ty4KqrTa%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%2Br4TaurGsmsb33y99Rq4fqr17Lr4Q66raqavLRtqlauFqrxFsq4a5vfWqOt2ZrWu6qb8sOwbJQOQN3x1C7dVmvKZpW0bA02Z7Yg6ladRNOEBv/A5svJdTHgADT%2B9YGp8d8IZAdSAElglOrgpUkHr4V2f6Ed2cagY0Brdg6nVNkkdUvFe3akfVSH0buwrvMZTZe3%2BQFCqeBITDCbEWXIxhASBViCHY3kwgy9YZTleF9hFpTtSs%2B6widQhIggM0nB1xs/3zXD7UCOKEqSlK0v10D5212XBLwJ0oJrf0ZkC3kmPu/84KWuCPYA%2BSEI5g4uYQHnHj5gXmOFgFgXZTkBElgg/hluX5UVmPIhVkNQPVzXiG16JdcLq3PcN21jdZeLEuS1KhBLzdfMqDlqkT23U7tR3UGgmYfznPN/a924/e9yynmRVH4XQAQwA4eVwQYVAH3hBBF7w1B4WATE7XlIg2RXpe3JYHDbQIZDJSD/YQ4HMViBSARsQjwXWVUEPuSb%2BOGFbpgJWyrO%2B6RZ4QklyoFEJcfEJBCQ2CEiwBYggURHiICJTeKIASYHfIYdA8JCToEwugQwBBaCiXAQkIhpJ16EGFqIXE8IJ5TwYDPOeC8l4ACUzDyhvkQh8lRaBXhsoJfCEsayOVNtXC2Qhlp3E7t3dcoECwgmLM6VyjZETIm0GwoS4DMKXEwYSVCJwIyoFQAkA21ojbFirubWu9cG4AL4fLAR3ZhEOydhyYKKjAEPgWLQTB8YQHPCoISPEgQUhYDwmfWghjjHW2bA4u8yAIlBCBAE1ALBuT%2BXONKPAvcwzIjQCQh0u8xCEiYOgUSOpfGgMwJghQCQqSYBMeGSk1IwjQjbvwqc3ZXLuT8vZc4PcioAOPg5U%2BeI8F1GIhReUC8d5nySKSSIZEMFslTJgbUu9MCqDwLFE2bAYHEHCtEvMccW60TafYjpNZe4NLDE0yELTVBnJ3hc70bk0m9JdgM5ENphln0JAoEwtB5RjKYGveEGytnTkOeGV4tyaSPLws8nsBxJB3CuVCgeW4R4ITghwOYtBOC7F4J4DgWhSCoE4Kw2K6JFgOXeDwUgZISW4rmOCEA/0nSxClFKaIPKGpcGiLsDQXhEb4o4JIIlmheDko4LwBQIAuqMq0HMOAsAkBoBYAkOgkRyCUHVZq%2BgUQGACgQAQ0SfAqILMoNLJlpAwhCn2ZweldrmD7OMmEbQzdHW8HVWwQQxkGCEMlaQLAFFgBOHjHK7gvAsBxiMOIG1%2BBIG2DFJG0lGyORyhWPS%2BZorSV2TCCJfZLgsBBoIB2FgXq5hUAMMABQCo8CYAfMZVCxL6X8EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6gbW6HqgYIwIBxb6DwGieAEBmBsBAAYFMoluR1FsMgUgN9HWSCVXMIx1RI06icCiBIBAdT0DFDwsqsQpU3w7FgOVsA53sCqakAQG6xAmBWOsDQ6weA9zaM3NIDgGDOFcM0PQ/hAi9BKP0VouRX3pDA6MRIyQEOTD6FEMY79qidAaCMFoAGP64e6FBqYsHLB1Dw0hgj4wSNFAwxIOY1KljdrxQSiVNrpVYLYcgeERrgAmsIcRXAhBcJ0pmLwRVzLSDIRKf0f0pBWWxGiE6DQGhogaEkNyyQDUGpSnWOsWm%2BhODitIMS0l0rZXyoZZK5VMBEAgAWAQPmFgKAQD1Vq4gwRWArHFrx8scRVO8BfYgvA6A9DtuEKIcQPbIv9rUEG4dpAHwiQSJW4zHBCVmaDdK4ycoXPwO4%2BYXj/HBNEIgC4DVnnz7qgkzZpl/7WWGadPpqU/L8bql2IZrwTVRWmfM1KzgVmFW2bYxwdYHGLNDfqzujdCygOSCAA)**)

If I understand correctly `.as_slice()` on a `Vec` is like C++ `.data()` on a `std::vector`, except it's a slice so it has a length.  Anyway, the idea is to avoid asking the compiler to actually store pointer and length to stack space.  But I'm not sure that worked: I am still seeing stores like `mov  [rsp + 24], r14` ; `mov  qword ptr [rsp + 32], 10` etc.

Using `Vec` in the first place is unnecessary; for these small sizes, just a slice in stack space would be fine, and probably would have avoided any alloc/dealloc overhead even if we had been cloning from constant slices since the compiler would know it could reuse stack space.

This function does a 240-byte `memcpy` of `TEST_VECS` to stack space every outer iteration.  (It copies from there to the `Vec` object.)  I don't know why that's happening, but I barely know Rust.  It happens without any use of `black_box` so it's not being triggered by that.

Answer (score -1):

### Correct way to test

Thanks to @PeterCordes

```rust
#![feature(test)]
#![allow(dead_code)]

use rand::Rng;

extern crate test;
fn selection_sort(original_vec: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in 0..original_vec.len() - 1 {
        let mut smallest: usize = i;
        for j in i + 1..original_vec.len() {
            if original_vec[j] < original_vec[smallest] {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        if smallest != i {
            original_vec.swap(i, smallest);
        }
    }
    original_vec.to_vec()
}

#[bench]
fn bench_rust_sort_10(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut v = (0..10)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(-2000..2000))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    b.iter(|| {
        v.iter_mut().for_each(|i| {
            *i ^= *i << 13;
            *i ^= *i >> 17;
            *i ^= *i << 5;
        });

        v.sort()
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_selection_sort_10(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut v = (0..10)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(-2000..2000))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    b.iter(|| {
        v.iter_mut().for_each(|i| {
            *i ^= *i << 13;
            *i ^= *i >> 17;
            *i ^= *i << 5;
        });
        selection_sort(&mut v);
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_rust_sort_1000(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut v = (0..1000)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(-2000..2000))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    b.iter(|| {
        v.iter_mut().for_each(|i| {
            *i ^= *i << 13;
            *i ^= *i >> 17;
            *i ^= *i << 5;
        });
        v.sort()
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_selection_sort_1000(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut v = (0..1000)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(-2000..2000))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    b.iter(|| {
        v.iter_mut().for_each(|i| {
            *i ^= *i << 13;
            *i ^= *i >> 17;
            *i ^= *i << 5;
        });
        selection_sort(&mut v);
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut v = (0..10)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(-2000..2000))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    let mut max_counter = vec![0; 10];

    (0..10000).for_each(|_| {
        v.iter_mut().for_each(|i| {
            *i ^= *i << 13;
            *i ^= *i >> 17;
            *i ^= *i << 5;
        });
        let max = v.iter().max().unwrap();
        let index = v.iter().position(|&r| r == *max).unwrap();
        max_counter[index] += 1;
        println!("{:?}",v);
        v.sort();
    });
    println!("{:?}", max_counter);
}
```

Test Result:

```bash
➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo bench
   Compiling bench v0.1.0 (/home/Murasame/Dev/bench)
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.41s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/bench-c25271d7fcaf578a)

running 4 tests
test bench_rust_sort_10        ... bench:          85 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_rust_sort_1000      ... bench:      28,793 ns/iter (+/- 231)
test bench_selection_sort_10   ... bench:         160 ns/iter (+/- 10)
test bench_selection_sort_1000 ... bench:     425,774 ns/iter (+/- 2,055)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 4 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 1.59s

➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo bench
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/bench-c25271d7fcaf578a)

running 4 tests
test bench_rust_sort_10        ... bench:          85 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_rust_sort_1000      ... bench:      28,685 ns/iter (+/- 144)
test bench_selection_sort_10   ... bench:         162 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test bench_selection_sort_1000 ... bench:     426,345 ns/iter (+/- 2,757)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 4 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 1.37s

➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo bench
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/bench-c25271d7fcaf578a)

running 4 tests
test bench_rust_sort_10        ... bench:          85 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_rust_sort_1000      ... bench:      28,681 ns/iter (+/- 860)
test bench_selection_sort_10   ... bench:         161 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test bench_selection_sort_1000 ... bench:     425,643 ns/iter (+/- 6,462)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 4 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 1.43s
```

The Cargo run:

```bash
➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo run  
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/bench`
[1032, 951, 1023, 985, 976, 1018, 986, 992, 1000, 1037]
➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/bench`
[1151, 972, 952, 1006, 969, 995, 988, 953, 989, 1025]
➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/bench`
[981, 946, 1006, 1031, 983, 999, 1003, 1069, 1047, 935]
```

---

### Another problem answer

If you are seeing this post, please read the comment for more information about this post.

Old answer is totally wrong.
Thanks to @PeterCordes;

```rust
#![feature(test)]
#![allow(dead_code)]

extern crate test;
use rand::Rng;
fn selection_sort(original_vec: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in 0..original_vec.len() - 1 {
        let mut smallest: usize = i;
        for j in i + 1..original_vec.len() {
            if original_vec[j] < original_vec[smallest] {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        if smallest != i {
            original_vec.swap(i, smallest);
        }
    }
    original_vec.to_vec()
}

#[bench]
fn bench_rust_sort_10(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    b.iter(|| {
        let mut v = (1..10).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..2000)).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
        v.sort()
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_selection_sort_10(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    b.iter(|| {
        let mut v = (1..10).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..2000)).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
            selection_sort(&mut v);
        }
    )
}

#[bench]
fn bench_rust_sort_1000(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    b.iter(|| {
        let mut v = (1..1000).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..2000)).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
        v.sort()
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_selection_sort_1000(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    b.iter(|| {
        let mut v = (1..1000).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..2000)).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
            selection_sort(&mut v);
        }
    )
}

fn main() {}
```

result:

```rust
➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo bench
   Compiling bench v0.1.0 (/home/Murasame/Dev/bench)
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.43s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/bench-c25271d7fcaf578a)

running 4 tests
test bench_rust_sort_10        ... bench:         125 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test bench_rust_sort_1000      ... bench:      33,482 ns/iter (+/- 196)
test bench_selection_sort_10   ... bench:         133 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test bench_selection_sort_1000 ... bench:     424,931 ns/iter (+/- 18,055)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 4 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.83s
```

---

##### Old answer below

---

### you are converting Type and Coping memory.

- Convert Array to Vector needs time.
- If you are coming from other languages, you should know the constant cannot be modify.

So you have to define the test set in the bench code.

- The `b:&mut test::Bencher` will be used for bench.
- The code out-side of `b.iter` will not be count in bench.

So you have to prepare your code like this:

```rust
#![feature(test)]
#![allow(dead_code)]
extern crate test;
fn selection_sort(original_vec: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in 0..original_vec.len()-1 {
        let mut smallest: usize = i;
        for j in i+1..original_vec.len() {
            if original_vec[j] < original_vec[smallest] {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        if smallest != i {
            original_vec.swap(i, smallest);
        }
    };
    original_vec.to_vec()
}

const TEST_VECS: [[i32; 10]; 6] = [
    [1, 3, 2, 9, 6, 7, 4, 10, 8, 5],
    [1, 2, 7, 2, 9, 9, 7, 10, 2, 1],
    [0, 4, 1, 3, 9, 12, 3, 0, 13, 8],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [-1, -5, -10, 1, 10, 2, -123, -34, 0, -32],
    [i32::MAX, -32984, i32::MIN, 31648, 5349857, -30954, -2343285, 0, 1, i32::MIN],
];

#[bench]
fn bench_rust_sort(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut test_vecs: Vec<Vec<i32>> = TEST_VECS.iter().map(|v| v.to_vec()).collect();
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in test_vecs.iter_mut() {
            i.sort()
        }
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_selection_sort(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut test_vecs: Vec<Vec<i32>> = TEST_VECS.iter().map(|v| v.to_vec()).collect();
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in test_vecs.iter_mut() {
            selection_sort(i);
        }
    })
}

fn main(){
    
}
```

Here is the result:

```bash
➜  bench git:(master) ✗ cargo bench
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/bench-5bf7ec1e7001cf33)

running 2 tests
test bench_rust_sort      ... bench:          43 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_selection_sort ... bench:         215 ns/iter (+/- 14)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 6.40s
```

My laptop running this bench:
MacBook Pro 2020 i5, 4 core 2.0Ghz.

Comment: [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) doesn't get faster when the data is already sorted (still O(N^2) comparisons), but Rust's built-in sort probably does (perhaps Insertion Sort for small problems, which does one pass in the already-sorted case).  You've changed the benchmark to keep sorting already-sorted arrays after the first iteration of the outer loop.  So of course Selection Sort is a lot slower than the best case of the builtin sort; the OP was trying to test its average case.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, thanks. I checked the bench's document. It will keep bench over and over again. but the test set has already changed after the first run.

Comment: Does `iter_mut` copy the vector in this function? It must always at least be copied, or else it will just sort the same sorted array. Unless there is some other way to only test the specific function call itself and not the copying required.

Comment: @yees_7: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html - it just gets an iterator that gives mutable references to the members of the collection.  Looping over it lets you modify the original.  It's like C++ `std::vector` `.begin` (as opposed to `.cbegin` to get a const (non mutable) iterator).  As I commented, this answer looks like it's sorting the already-sorted data, which explains why it's so much faster.

Comment: @yees_7 Please don't think this answer is right. You can think the `iter_mut` is making every field in array/vector is mutable referenced by default

Comment: @PeterCordes I think we can done it better with rand.

Comment: @Murasame I unmarked the answer. Does that mean that the way I did it in the question post was correct? I tried to do a similar thing I did in the post but with moving the vector conversion inside the function but outside the closure, but it gave a similar result to yours.

Comment: Generating fresh random numbers between sorts is slower than a couple `movups` load/store instructions!  With a counted repeat loop (instead of the bench loop) around the OP's selection_sort loop so I can get https://rust.godbolt.org/z/a6zYzh5dv to show me the asm, it looks like overhead is very minimal, just the 40-byte copy (which will hit in L1d cache).  It takes 3 loads and 3 stores, 2 of them using 16-byte XMM vectors, one using an 8-byte integer reg.  Store-forwarding makes this work nicely when the sort code starts reloading it, no stalling.  (Yes, @yees_7, your results should be good)

Comment: Re-randomizing every time means that branch-prediction isn't going to learn the patterns, if that was happening with 6 different arrays.  If you used a fast PRNG like xorshift+, you wouldn't be adding much constant overhead to the sort times.  e.g. in C++ with AVX2 intrinsics, you could be generating 32 bytes of randomness at a time with a few instructions, as in [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324520) (it doesn't have to be high-quality randomness to test a sort).

Comment: It sounds like a good way to test, and was one of the things I thought about while making the testing function. My main concern with it was that it would generate different vectors for each testing function, so it wouldn't really compare the two for the same input. Should I worry about this or should I just care that it's testing an average of the sort?

Comment: Re: your update: now you're sorting 1001 element arrays so built-in `.sort()` is of course vastly faster than `selection_sort()`.  That's not what @yees_7 was testing.  They found that their `selection_sort` was about the same speed or slightly faster than `.sort()` for 10-element arrays, and I think that was a correct measurement.  Your answer gives the impression that there was something wrong with that.

Comment: @PeterCordes But that's okay because we are testing the sort algorithm.
And the thread_rng's performance is suit for this case.

Comment: @yees_7: Check with `perf stat` to see if branch mispredict rate is very low.  If so, then your CPU is "learning" the pattern of branching across all 6 sorts.  That's unrealistic for most cases except when already-sorted arrays are common, and then you'd avoid Selection Sort like the plague.  If you want to see what difference that makes, make TEST_VECS smaller, like maybe only one 10-element vector.  (IIRC, my Skylake CPU learned the pattern of branching in a hand-written asm Bubble Sort for sizes up to about 14 elements re-sorting the same unsorted input repeatedly, with near 0 mispredicts)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think make four test is suit for our target.

Comment: Yes, testing both small 10-element and 1000-element sorts makes more sense, showing the obvious point that an O(N^2) algorithm gets really slow for larger inputs.  Your numbers don't seem very stable between edits, though; 424,931 ns / iter this time for 1000 element selection_sort, vs. 316,458 ns/iter for 1001 element selection_sort.  But I'm still not convinced that there was anything really wrong with @yees_7 's original way of testing.  Doesn't `.as_vec()` make a copy?  You complain that converting an array to a vector needs time, but so does generating random numbers with ChaCha12!

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm guessing you want me to `perf stat cargo bench` (I might be wrong). If so, it gave me two results for the amount of branch misses: `98.52%` for `cpu_core/branch-misses/u` and `1.54%` for `cpu-atom/branch-misses/u`. I don't really know much about computer architecture so I have no clue what the difference is, but what would these results mean?

Comment: @PeterCordes He wants to know why his custom sort is 'faster' than rust sort. He needs to test a large sets but he didn't. I get the main problem wrong, I think the memory copy is the main problem. Now I think current answer is still have problem. Rand is not a stable way to create test set. And collect to vector still have cost. I think I can make a mutable vector for contain testset. and use something like XOR with bit-shift for generate random to stable the time.

Comment: @yees_7: `perf stat` on my Skylake just shows a `branches` and `branch-misses` event, not `cpu_core` vs. `cpu-atom`.  Maybe that's an Alder Lake P-core vs. E-core think since the E cores are derived from Silvermont Atom?  1.54% looks plausible; some of the branching is loops with fixed counts.  But it's still pretty low, try a larger TEST_VECS and/or larger arrays to see if it changes much. 98.5% is not plausible; even random guessing would be right about 50% of the time, and it's unlikely that you randomly found a pessimal case that tricks branch prediction into being worse than random guess.

Comment: @Murasame: Copying some test vectors is the fastest way to re-generate the same inputs for a sort.  I looked at the asm on Godbolt (in an earlier comment) and it really is just 3 loads and 3 stores.  (Or two with `-C target-cpu=x86-64-v3` to allow AVX: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ob7o7119Y see the `vmovups ymm0, [r14]`.)  It's not allocating new space every time, it's allocating stack space once at the top of the function.  The only downside is the same pattern of branching every time, but if you have enough different vectors the CPU won't learn the pattern.

Comment: If you did want to use a PRNG, generating numbers in a limited range is slower: to avoid bias, it has to discard some samples.  https://github.com/al-jshen/alea/tree/master/benches has some benchmarks of a custom prng vs. the standard one, which is ChaCha12, a CSPRNG.  (https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html).  It's fast for a CSPRNG, but PRNGs that aren't trying to be cryptographically secure can be even faster.

Comment: Using AVX2 to do some xors and shifts on 32 bytes at once is also fast if you want to sort different data each time; that's basically the xorshift+ PRNG, which my answer on [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324520) shows (with C++ intrinsics).  Running four generators in parallel in the 64-bit elements of AVX2 vectors gives us excellent throughput, only a few instructions per 32 bytes of randomness (8x i32).  Only a bit more expensive than just copying, but gives different data each time.

Comment: Since you mention "stable", you could use the same seed for the same PRNG in both Rust and selection sorts.  Apparently  rand::rngs::ThreadRngCopy reseeds itself from OsRng every 64KiB, so that's definitely not what you want.  Besides making some runs slower when it reseeds, it won't be the same sequence.  Use something simple and very fast like XorShift+, preferably in parallel so it can vectorize.

Comment: @yees_7: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/perf-stat.1.html confirms that `cpu_core/` and `cpu_atom/` are indeed the P cores and E cores of a hybrid CPU.  Probably best to `taskset -c 1  perf stat  cargo bench` or something so your code doesn't bounce around between CPU cores.  (Doesn't have to be core #1, pick a P core or an E core.)

Comment: Re: your last edit, to ADD and XOR the sort results with two loop-invariant numbers.  Depending on what you randomly generate, that might or might not change their order much, so you're probably still testing the most-sorted case for .sort, not the average case which is O(N^2) like Selection Sort.  With full-range `i32` values (and .wrapping_add) you would sometimes be making a positive value negative which creates more sorting work.  Adding the same number to every element does nothing except for interacting with the XOR; it's the only thing that might change the order.

Comment: Randomly generating `x` and `y` seems bad; if you get a pair that rarely changes the order of elements, you're stuck with that for the whole benchmark function.  Picking some good ones like perhaps `y=0xffffcccc` might be good to always flip lots of bits.  Or do `(x - v[i]) ^ y` since negating each element will tend to make a reverse-sorted array that needs a maximal amount of data movement.  (Selection Sort doesn't care, it always does the same amount of work, so that would make Selection look good compared to Insertion Sort where that is the worst case.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I find the best way to generate the numbers.

Comment: Ok, so you're doing one iteration of an [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register).  If it auto-vectorizes, it'll have a store-forwarding stall from a SIMD load on a small array just written with scalar stores, unlike using a vectorized PRNG, but it's saving a bit of front-end throughput in not having to store back to a separate seed vector as well as storing a result.  [Can modern x86 implementations store-forward from more than one prior store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46135766)

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. You are giving me lots of ideas for ways to benchmark correctly, however I feel that you are starting to drift away from the actual question. I simply asked if my code was benchmarking correctly and why selection sort seems to be faster, which both seem to be answered by @PeterCordes in the comments, not the _best_ way to benchmark sorting functions. I think this answer is better suited in a question asking the best way to benchmark a sorting algorithm, or just in the comments of this post for extra info.

Comment: `(0..9).for_each` seems weird to me, having to hard-code the length somewhere else.  Can't you do something like `v.for_each(|x| { x ^= x << 13;  ... });` (or `mut &x`?) or [How to loop over a vector of integers in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66092442)

Comment: @PeterCordes thats a typo. It needs to be fix. Correct answer is (0..10)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the `iter_mut` is slower? I don't know why.

Comment: @PeterCordes And I have to let you know: (0..10) means 0-9 not 0-10. I think you may not be clear on how Range works in rust.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed wrong that it would include both ends, but it's actually like a `for(i=start ; i<end; i++)` not including the end.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/range-expr.html .  I barely know Rust, but I understand performance of the machine code / asm it compiles to (and I know `rustc` uses LLVM's optimizer so it normally compiles similarly to the way C or C++ would when you write stuff that does the same work.)  Questions like this are fun way to learn some about languages I'm interested in.

Comment: IDK why `iter_mut` would be slower; perhaps a quirk of code layout in how it compiled? 
 Or that was because my wrong guess had the previous version not doing a shift/xor on the last element, so doing less work.  And unfortunately it didn't vectorize in a way that did the last 1 or 2 elements with SIMD to make the speed about the same; compilers tend to be bad at using narrow vectors for cleanup.  Your 2020 i5 MBP should be an Ice Lake if review sites are right, so [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646) won't affect it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have a lots of friends doing Programming language research. We all agree that Rust is a well designed language. If you interested in it, you should learn it.

Comment: @PeterCordes And I find an issue talks about `iter_mut`. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31890

Comment: I posted an answer with some details confirming that the OP's measurement makes sense, and about how to avoid alloc/dealloc overhead while copying using `.clone_from_slice()`.  I was wrong earlier and missed the `call` in the original asm.